# Derby Trigger on UPDATE: how to update a timestamp?

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, derby, triggers

Short: How to create a trigger on a Apache Derby DB which updates the timestamps on changed records?

---

Adapting an existing project to use Apache Derby as database software,
I have encountered several problems. Most I could solve using stackoverflow and a search engine,
but for this one I ask your help.

With other DB software, I'd be doing something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
…
`lastchange` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
…
)
```

Derby doesn't like ` and you have to create triggers separately.
So I try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTimestamp AFTER UPDATE ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
(UPDATE mytable SET lastchange= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )
```

and I get an error. Oh, this update might cause the trigger to go off again... so

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTimestamp NO CASCADE BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
(UPDATE mytable SET lastchange= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )
```

would be better, right?

Well, either gives me an error telling Derby doesn't like the second "UPDATE" in this statement.
But I don't want to insert or delete anything, I want to *update* the timestamp on the rows that have been changed/will be changed.

How to do that?

------ Update ------

When there is no logical solution, trying some magic may help.

I removed the brackets (even though the Derby documentation and examples had them).

Derby tells me it doesn't like BEFORE on UPDATE triggers (wtf?), so I went back to AFTER, assuming Derby knows what it is doing there.

And finally, while CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a function, Derby objected to the brackets, so I removed them as well. Looks weird, but if that's what Derby wants...

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTimestamp AFTER UPDATE ON votes FOR EACH ROW UPDATE 
votes SET lastvoted = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Now *this* was accepted by Apache Derby. But executing it caused a trigger loop, as was to be expected with AFTER. So, still no solution.

How is this done? It's so simple on other Databases. There's got to be a solution for Derby, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, you have to specify **every** column in the table that you want to listen for updates (obviously excluding the *lastvoted* column).

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTimestamp
AFTER UPDATE OF col1, col2, col3... ON votes
REFERENCING OLD AS EXISTING
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    UPDATE votes SET lastvoted = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE pkcolumn = EXISTING.pkcolumn
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify updated column, it should work:

> CREATE TRIGGER updateTimestamp AFTER UPDATE OF updatedcolumn ON votes
>   REFERENCING OLD AS old FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL UPDATE votes SET
>   lastvoted = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE yourprimarykeycolumn=old.yourprimarykeycolumn;